# Can I query the Android Market License server from application A in order to see if application B was bought legitimately from the market?

Tags: android, google-play, android-preferences, android-lvl

I have app A which is free. I have app B which is a donation app. I know people rather pay 4 bucks for coffee and get my app for free via other channels but oh well.

I want to enable more features in app A if app B is legit and from the market and paid for.

So I was curious if I just change the package name in the Market License code in order to check for app B even though app A is executing it.

For example, this line is from the lvl library code:

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker(ctx, new ServerManagedPolicy(ctx,
new AESObfuscator(SALT, ctx.getPackageName(), deviceId)),
BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

I would like to replace ctx.getPackageName() with the package name from app B, which of course is my app and I know. For example:

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker(ctx, new ServerManagedPolicy(ctx,
new AESObfuscator(SALT, com.something.app.b, deviceId)),
BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: 5 months later, I get a random downvote on this... Does someone know something I dont? Please feel free to comment and help out.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now. Have you found a solution? I am adding IAP into my app, but I desperately need to make sure those users who purchased another UNLOCKER/DONATION app will keep their privilegue. Thanks a lot for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the arguments to the obfuscator constructor isn't going to do what you want. The package that is checked is determined by the LicenseChecker constructor from the first argument. It might work to define a new constructor for LicenseChecker that takes a package name and version code for package B.

If app A also wants to check its own license, you'll need to extend ServerManagedPolicy as well so that it keeps separate cache data for each app in app A's preferences file.

Note that even if this works, it will break if you update app B in the market, because you will need to wire in a specific version code into app A.

Comment: Do you think perhaps sharing the preferences is a better route?

Comment: That might make sense. App A could access App B's cached validation data and verify that it's current, using pretty much the same logic as the default policy uses. (If app B hasn't been validated, app A can assume it wouldn't validate and never make a query to the license server. That isn't 100% correct, but might be good enough for your particular purposes. You might need to modify the licensing library that B uses so that the results can be decrypted by app A. I think the default encryption can't be shared.

Comment: Makes sense... Could even just access B's mode_private if they are signed with the same certificate and read the cached result without encryption. If it is real time, it should not make a difference if encrypted or not. Or?