# Android: Check a license status of app A from app B?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I have a FREE app and a DONATION app. I've decided to add some paid options into my FREE app, however I want to make sure that users who had already purchased my DONATION app will get an access.

I know you can check a purchasing status of any app using LVL - however, can you check a purchase status of DIFFERENT app from within YOUR app?

Similar question: [Can I query the Android Market License server from application A in order to see if application B was bought legitimately from the market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843770/can-i-query-the-android-market-license-server-from-application-a-in-order-to-see?rq=4)